# sed r command example explanation is needed

Tags: sed

```
$cat rgb
lower (#1): "red green blue"
UPPER (#2): "RED GREEN BLUE"

$seq 2 | sed '1r /dev/stdin' rgb
lower (#1): "red green blue"
1
2
UPPER (#2): "RED GREEN BLUE"
```

I don't understand why 2 is printed. 2 is at line 2, then why is it printed??

Comment: who voted the -1? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The command `seq 2` prints

```
1
2
```

to the standard output stream, and `sed '1r /dev/stdin' rgb` reads it from the standard input stream and inserts it after the first line of file `rgb`.

Comment: actually, sed appends it after the first line of file rgb.